# Print Directory to file

Tags: windows-10

I have a BAT file which will print the current DIR to the printer.
I wish to have it display a file on the screen only, not the printer.

```
@echo off 
dir %1 /-p /o:gn > "%temp%\Listing" 
start /w notepad /p "%temp%\Listing 
del "%temp%\Listing" 
exit
```

Comment: Replace `start /w notepad /p` with `type`.

Comment: So just run `dir %1 /-p /o:gn` only and nothing else. If you wish to open it with Notepad rather than print it, then run `notepad "%temp%\Listing"`  and not ``start /w notepad /p "%temp%\Listing"``

Comment: Thank you for the answer.   Okay now.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `/p` of notepad is defined as:

> /P  print filename

So just take it off.

A second problem is that the `start` command will run in parallel with the `del`
command, and the delete might even happen before notepad has read the file.
I suggest not using `start`, like this:

```
@echo off 
dir %1 /-p /o:gn > "%temp%\Listing" 
notepad /p "%temp%\Listing 
del "%temp%\Listing"
```

An `exit` command is not required, as this is implicit with the end of the `.bat` file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.   Okay now.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (tick the V sign). See [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use start or /p switch with notepad...

```
@echo off 
dir %1 /-p /o:gn > "%temp%\Listing.txt" 
notepad "%temp%\Listing 
del "%temp%\Listing.txt" 
exit
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.   Okay now.